# How can i change the SSH port used on Plesk 9 for Migration Manager?

Tags: linux, ssh, migration

My hosting company have a non standard SSH port configured on my current server, i am now looking to migrate to a new server and want to use the Plesk Migration Manager, however it seems that you cannot specify the port in the host name like 127.0.0.1:xxx

Any ideas? and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access, you should be able to modify your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to change the port back to 22.  Then restart SSH ("/etc/init.d/sshd restart" or "service ssh restart" on some distributions.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the default port used by the standard ssh client by editing the "Port 22" line in /etc/ssh/ssh_config (your config file location may differ).